# Is there a shortcut to bootstrapping a new REACT app?

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

I am new to REACT and wondering if there is a speedier way to get started with a new React app? Presently, I need to do the following and wait for the commands to complete:

- npx create-react-app app1
- npm install @material-ui/core
- npm install @material-ui/icons
- npm install react-number-format
- npm install fontsource-roboto
- ..
  These cmd have to repeated for each application and requires several minutes for each.
  Is there a shortcut? Can I change the application name once its created by npx cmd?

Comment: You could create a template git repository and clone from that every time.

Comment: Can I change the app name after cloning it from github?

Comment: The result of all those commands can be summed up as one thing: they write things to files. All those files are in github, and yes you can change those files.

Answer (score 0):

You can glue commands and go to drink tea:

```
npx create-react-app app1 && cd ./app1 && npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons react-number-format fontsource-roboto
```

`&&` operator will hold a command until previous one done.

You can read that instruction as these steps:

1. Please, run `npx create-react-app app1` command.
2. After that, please, change current directory to directory with new project.
3. After that instal these packages with `npm install`.

You can pass as arguments to `npm install` few packages using space symbol.

If it's really repeats from project to project, you can create your own shell script to initialize some boilerplate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking more of saving time doing this activity for each new React application. Could I make one boiler plate and copy it for any new one?

Comment: Yes, you can. But packages version will not be update. It's a bad. Just try to use `yarn` instead of `npm`, because he works quickly. :)